# In hidden part of div :hover still works and is visible

Tags: jquery, css, html, slide

I have a simple coding: http://jsfiddle.net/8AMa4/20/ (the stupid colors just for indication ;))

Basically it does work, but with a glitch I don't know how to fix. In the div there are picture "pages", that slide to the side as you press the buttons and only one is visible at a time. When you hover a visible picture some fading in appears. Problem is that this fading in on hover appears in the supposed-to-be-hidden part of the div too. (You can see it in the jsfiddle example, if you move your mouse to the right side of the man div).

Can anyone hep me with a solution? where should I change either of the 2 "effect" (the hover and the sliding)?

HTML:

```
<div class="tab-box">

  <div class="tabs">
    <div class="tab">1</div>
    <div class="tab">2</div>
    <div class="tab">3</div>
  </div>

  <div class="items">
    <div class="item" style="background: red;">
        <a href="#"><span class="rollover"></span><img class="thumbnail" alt="" src="http://www.sxc.hu/pic/m/s/sk/skapie/1218910_guitar.jpg"/></a>
    </div>
    <div class="item" style="background: blue;">
        <a href="#"><span class="rollover"></span><img class="thumbnail" alt="" src="http://www.sxc.hu/pic/m/s/sk/skapie/1218910_guitar.jpg"/></a>
    </div>
    <div class="item" style="background: green;">
         <a href="#"><span class="rollover"></span><img class="thumbnail" alt="" src="http://www.sxc.hu/pic/m/s/sk/skapie/1218910_guitar.jpg" /></a> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.tab-box').each(function() {
        var left = 0;
        var $tabbox = $(this);
        var width = $tabbox.width();

        $(this).find('.tab').each(function() {
            var shift = left;

            $(this).click(function() {
                $tabbox.find('.items').animate({marginLeft: shift + 'px'});
                $tabbox.find('.tab').removeClass('active');
                $(this).addClass('active');
            });

            left -= width;
        });

        $(this).find('.tab:eq(0)').addClass('active');
    });

});
```

Comment: Please include your code, not just a link to jsfiddle.

Comment: Szandra: as @JamesMontagne said, this time I fixed it *for* you, but in future please do include (relevant) code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed a `position:relative` at the `.tab-box`.

Working:
http://jsfiddle.net/8AMa4/26/

Comment: OMG. Such a small error. Thank you sooooooo much :) Sorry for forgetting the code, I'm not used to asking :)